# How to fix error file not found :(.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0) when build project Qt?

Tags: qt

When I build Qt project ( Qt 5) , I faced with error

> file not found :(.qtversion[qt_version_tag]+0x0).

Please help me resolve this issue
Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: Please be very specific. How exactly are you building the project (from the command line? from an IDE?)? What is the project - is it your own project? An open source project? Can you share the `.pro` file? What is the platform - OS and version, compiler and version, what is the *full* Qt version, where did you get the Qt binaries from (installer vs. self-compiled), etc. As it stands, there's no way for us to help you.

Comment: Hello Kuba, 
thank you for your comment , 
- i used IDE Qt 5.7.0 , 
- i build project with libssh library ( it open source) , 
- the platform is Linux , ubuntu 14.04 , 
- Qt version : , 
- i got  the Qt from Qt Download.